# How to use ExpressVPN inside virtual box using "Bridged Adapter"

Tags: windows, virtualbox, vpn, virtual-machine, openvpn

ExpressVPN has an option called split tunnel which can connect only certain applications to the VPN network, I have tried it and it worked, but the problem is:
1- I must turn on the VPN on my desktop for it to work and if it fails or disconnects it will use my main home network
2- When I use "Bridged Adapter" network on the VPN and chose ExpressVPN adapter network it does not work

What I am looking for:
I want the Virtual Box to connect and use only the ExpressVPN network "Bridged Adapter", in that case if the ExpressVPN failed and disconnected in anyway the whole traffic will stop and my main IP address will not be exposed

I do not know what I am doing wrong and how I can select the "Bridged Adapter" network on the virtual box and make it work, here is a pic below of the option I am trying to work with but it's not work:

[image]

Comment: I think you mean you set VBOX for the Bridged NIC. That is a connection via your router. Have you tried NAT instead.

Comment: Hello @John , the NAT network is my main network, I want to access the Virtual Box using the ExpressVPN adapter network so it does not get my IP in case it went off

Comment: You think the adapter part is a separated router connected to my PC using the ExpressVPN network?

Comment: The Bridged NIC adapter connects to your physical router, and a NAT adapter connects to the VBOX internal DHCP server. You can try NAT and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you John for sharing, I am just confused how to do all of this, doing more research at the moment

Comment: VPN does not normally work inside a virtual guest macihne, so I probably cannot help you further.